# Displaying query result on same page PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using a PHP script to add a record into my database, this works properly after some debugging. When the script runs, it opens a new page with the query output.

I'd like to display the query output on the same page that executes the query, at the top of the page, under my navbar.

Below is my current page.
[image]

This is the desired result.
[image]

The relevant code of the HTML page:

```
  <form name="registration" action="addKlant.php" target="_blank" method="post">
    <h3><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Klant toevoegen</h3>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Naam</label>
      <input type="text" name="klantNaam">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Soort klant</label>
      <select class="" name="klantSoort">
        <option value="">Bedrijf</option>
        <option value="">Particulier</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Telefoonnummer</label>
      <input type="number" name="klantTel">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> E-mail adres</label>
      <input type="email" name="klantEmail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Straat & huisnr</label>
      <input type="text" name="klantAdres">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Postcode</label>
      <input type="text" name="klantPostcode">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Plaats</label>
      <input type="text" name="klantPlaats">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Klant toevoegen">
    </div>
  </form>
```

addKlant.php

```
<?php
require('db.php');

$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO `klanten` (klant_naam, klant_soort, klant_telefoon, klant_email, klant_straat, klant_postcode, klant_plaats) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

if($stmt) {
  $klant_naam = $_POST['klantNaam'];
  $klant_soort = $_POST['klantSoort'];
  $klant_telefoon = $_POST['klantTel'];
  $klant_email = $_POST['klantEmail'];
  $klant_adres = $_POST['klantAdres'];
  $klant_postcode = $_POST['klantPostcode'];
  $klant_plaats = $_POST['klantPlaats'];

  $stmt->bind_param('ssissss', $klant_naam, $klant_soort, $klant_telefoon, $klant_email, $klant_adres, $klant_postcode, $klant_plaats);

  $stmt->execute();

  $con->close();

  echo "Klant is toegevoegd, je kan deze pagina nu sluiten.";
}

?>
```

I was thinking about using something like `if($_POST)`? But I do not know how to implement it exactly.

It does not matter if the page refreshes to add the output, but I would like to keep it to PHP and not use JS (of course, if it is possible with only PHP).

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Edited my code with some help from @SloanTrasher**

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit'] == 'Klant toevoegen') {
  require('db.php');

  $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO `klanten` (klant_naam, klant_soort, klant_telefoon, klant_email, klant_straat, klant_postcode, klant_plaats) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

  if($stmt) {
    $klant_naam = $_POST['klantNaam'];
    $klant_soort = $_POST['klantSoort'];
    $klant_telefoon = $_POST['klantTel'];
    $klant_email = $_POST['klantEmail'];
    $klant_adres = $_POST['klantAdres'];
    $klant_postcode = $_POST['klantPostcode'];
    $klant_plaats = $_POST['klantPlaats'];

    $stmt->bind_param('ssissss', $klant_naam, $klant_soort, $klant_telefoon, $klant_email, $klant_adres, $klant_postcode, $klant_plaats);

    $stmt->execute();

    $con->close();

  }
}

?>


<!-- I placed it above the form for simplification -->
<?php ($_POST['submit'] == 'Klant toevoegen') {echo "<p>Klant is toegevoegd.</p>";}?>

<form name="registration" action="addKlant.php" target="_blank" method="post">
    <h3><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Klant toevoegen</h3>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Naam</label>
      <input type="text" name="klantNaam">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Soort klant</label>
      <select class="" name="klantSoort">
        <option value="">Bedrijf</option>
        <option value="">Particulier</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Telefoonnummer</label>
      <input type="number" name="klantTel">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> E-mail adres</label>
      <input type="email" name="klantEmail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Straat & huisnr</label>
      <input type="text" name="klantAdres">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Postcode</label>
      <input type="text" name="klantPostcode">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Plaats</label>
      <input type="text" name="klantPlaats">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Klant toevoegen">
    </div>
  </form>
```

**EDIT 2: Working code for anyone interested**

```
<?php
include('auth.php');
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Klant toevoegen') {
  require('db.php');

  $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO `klanten` (klant_naam, klant_soort, klant_telefoon, klant_email, klant_straat, klant_postcode, klant_plaats) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

  if($stmt) {
    $klant_naam = $_POST['klantNaam'];
    $klant_soort = $_POST['klantSoort'];
    $klant_telefoon = $_POST['klantTel'];
    $klant_email = $_POST['klantEmail'];
    $klant_adres = $_POST['klantAdres'];
    $klant_postcode = $_POST['klantPostcode'];
    $klant_plaats = $_POST['klantPlaats'];

    $stmt->bind_param('ssissss', $klant_naam, $klant_soort, $klant_telefoon, $klant_email, $klant_adres, $klant_postcode, $klant_plaats);

    $stmt->execute();

    $con->close();

  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Charset, viewport en keywords -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Titel en favicon -->
    <title></title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./img/favicon.jpg">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/pageForward.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/pageBack.js"></script>

    <!-- Stylesheets en fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/backend_styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:200" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; -->
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top-links">
        <p><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a><a href="geavanceerd.php"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></a><a onclick="goBack()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a><a onclick="goForward()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a> Backoffice | Ingelogt als: <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];  ?> |<a href="logout.php"> Uitloggen</a></p>
      </div>
      <?php if($_POST['submit'] == 'Klant toevoegen') {echo "<p>Klant is toegevoegd.</p>";}?>
      <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="backend-form">
          <form name="registration" method="post">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Klant toevoegen</h3>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Naam</label>
              <input type="text" name="klantNaam">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Soort klant</label>
              <select class="" name="klantSoort">
                <option value="Bedrijf">Bedrijf</option>
                <option value="Particulier">Particulier</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Telefoonnummer</label>
              <input type="number" name="klantTel">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> E-mail adres</label>
              <input type="email" name="klantEmail">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Straat & huisnr</label>
              <input type="text" name="klantAdres">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Postcode</label>
              <input type="text" name="klantPostcode">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Plaats</label>
              <input type="text" name="klantPlaats">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Klant toevoegen">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2018</p>
      </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your insert code into the top of your form page, and enclose in an ```if($_POST['submit'] == 'Klant toevoegen') {``` statement. Move the ```echo``` statement to the proper location in your HTML, and also include it in an if statement with the same condition.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I edited my code, is this what you meant? I assume that I could also place it in a div to style it according to the result. Red for error and green for success. I will be able to figure this out myself though :).

Comment: Looks right. Did it produce the results you want?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I just implemented it in my test enviroment and it works like a charm. Could you create an awnser so I can accept it?

Comment: See my "answer below" and thanks for thinking pf giving me credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working code. Glad you got it working!

```
<?php
include('auth.php');
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Klant toevoegen') {
  require('db.php');

  $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO `klanten` (klant_naam, klant_soort, klant_telefoon, klant_email, klant_straat, klant_postcode, klant_plaats) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

  if($stmt) {
    $klant_naam = $_POST['klantNaam'];
    $klant_soort = $_POST['klantSoort'];
    $klant_telefoon = $_POST['klantTel'];
    $klant_email = $_POST['klantEmail'];
    $klant_adres = $_POST['klantAdres'];
    $klant_postcode = $_POST['klantPostcode'];
    $klant_plaats = $_POST['klantPlaats'];

    $stmt->bind_param('ssissss', $klant_naam, $klant_soort, $klant_telefoon, $klant_email, $klant_adres, $klant_postcode, $klant_plaats);

    $stmt->execute();

    $con->close();

  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Charset, viewport en keywords -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Titel en favicon -->
    <title></title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./img/favicon.jpg">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/pageForward.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/pageBack.js"></script>

    <!-- Stylesheets en fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/backend_styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:200" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; -->
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="top-links">
        <p><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a><a href="geavanceerd.php"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></a><a onclick="goBack()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a><a onclick="goForward()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a> Backoffice | Ingelogt als: <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];  ?> |<a href="logout.php"> Uitloggen</a></p>
      </div>
      <?php if($_POST['submit'] == 'Klant toevoegen') {echo "<p>Klant is toegevoegd.</p>";}?>
      <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="backend-form">
          <form name="registration" method="post">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Klant toevoegen</h3>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Naam</label>
              <input type="text" name="klantNaam">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Soort klant</label>
              <select class="" name="klantSoort">
                <option value="Bedrijf">Bedrijf</option>
                <option value="Particulier">Particulier</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Telefoonnummer</label>
              <input type="number" name="klantTel">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> E-mail adres</label>
              <input type="email" name="klantEmail">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Straat & huisnr</label>
              <input type="text" name="klantAdres">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Postcode</label>
              <input type="text" name="klantPostcode">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <label><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Plaats</label>
              <input type="text" name="klantPlaats">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Klant toevoegen">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2018</p>
      </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming that the HTML form is not part of addKlant.php?
In which case, once you've processed the form, you might want to redirect to the page with the HTML form, and pass an item in the querystring with some sort of variable to show the query has run.

i.e.

```
// ... after your form processing
$con->close();
header("Location: htmlpage.php?queryresult=ok");
exit;
```

and then in the HTML form page:

```
<?php if ($_GET['queryresult'] == 'ok') print "query ran okay"; ?>
```

I don't know what the result of the query might look like - if it is encodable within a url, you can pass this whole response, ie.

```
header("Location: htmlpage.php?queryresult=" . urlencode( $queryresultstring ));
```